# End of session if exit command run in parallel to different command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have found a behavior of shell I don't understand. When you execute

```
echo foo > /tmp/bar & exit
```

, the terminal is closed. But when you execute

```
exit & echo foo > /tmp/bar
```

, the terminal stays open and something like

```
[1] 4001
```

is printed on it.

The output of the first version can be seen, too, if you log into a different account using `su`, because then, only the session of the user you logged in to using `su` is ended and your terminal stays open. It's something like:

```
[2] 13777
exit
[1]+  Done                    exit
```

Why isn't the session ended if `exit` is the first command?

Just in case you can't replicate this on your Unix system: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first command,

```
echo foo > /tmp/bar & exit
```

starts a subshell in the background to run `echo foo > /tmp/bar`, and exits (the foreground shell). This closes your terminal, in the same way as simply typing `exit`. The background shell won't stay around very long at all, so you won't get a race; but if you do this with a longer-running command, depending on your shell and your options, you'll get different behaviours:

```
sleep 60 & exit
```

might not exit but complain that you have running jobs instead.

In both these cases, the shell does print a line of the form `[1] 7149` but if your terminal closes you won't have time to see it.

Your second command,

```
exit & echo foo > /tmp/bar
```

starts a subshell in the background to run `exit`, which exits (from the subshell), and runs `echo foo > /tmp/bar`. So the “main” shell doesn't exit and the terminal stays open, which allows you to see

```
[2] 13777
```

followed by

```
exit
```

(printed by the shell exiting) and then

```
[1]+  Done                    exit
```

(printed by the main shell when the background shell exits).

Comment: Is which command is executed in the subshell and which one in the original one documented behavior or up to implementation?

Comment: It's whichever command is followed by `&`; see for example the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) for documentation on this.